# Ideal Switching Signal for a Featherwing power Relay board

Tags: transistors, relay

The featherwing power relay board is a simple transistor controlled electromechanical relay.

The power supplied is 3.3V and it requires a signal to switch.

Looking at the data sheet, the signal voltage is not specified.

https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/adafruit-power-relay-featherwing.pdf

From the schematic, any voltage above 0.7V should switch the switch.  Is there an ideal safe switching voltage and how is it calculated or is it rule of thumb, i.e same as collector or random sensible value?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, any voltage above 0.7V will not cause the "switch to switch". You need to think about how much current the relay needs, and how much current must flow into the base of the transistor.

Now, the relay needs 100mA and lets assume that the \$h_{fe}\$ of the transistor is at least 50. That means you need at least 2mA into the base of the transistor to get 100mA to the relay.

Assume that the base-emitter voltage is 0.7V, which means that 0.07mA flows through R2 to ground. By KCL we need at least 2.07mA to flow through R1, and by Ohm's Law that means the voltage across R1 must be at least 2.07V. Using KVL, the input voltage must be the voltage across R1 plus the voltage from the base to emitter, for a total of 2.77V. This was all back-of-the-envelope estimation, but I would say that the input needs to be above 3V to reliably "switch the switch". You want to provide enough base current that the transistor goes into saturation in order to minimize power dissipation (and heat).

Answer (score 1):

Obtain Relay coil resistance , DCR

You assumed fixed choice Vcc=3.3 V DCR which will be lower than say 12V relay by similar Voltage ratio for same power.

Transistor gain is hFE =10 for Vce=Vce(sat) which reduces V to coil to about 3V.

The input R1 may need to be reduced.

Vin=Vcoil* R1/(10* DCR) +0.7